# What's a good Windows PIM program with synchronisation support?

Tags: windows, sync, calendar, tasks, pim

## Summary

I have been looking for a good personal information management (PIM) program with good online synchronisation support for a long time. Does anyone know of one that meets my needs?

## Requirements

The following are essential for an acceptable solution.

- Windows 8 64-bit support
- Calendars and task lists

  - Multiple calendars/task lists
  - Repeating events/tasks
- Bidirectional online synchronisation with a free service or services

  - This can be one service provider (such as Google) or multiple (such as Google for calendar and something else for tasks).
- Multiple accounts
- Stability (crashes and glitches should be occasional or less frequent)
- Reliable (no data loss)
- Reminders

## Optional Preferences

The following are desired, but optional. They may be subjective and are not required for an accepted solution. However, a solution that meets the requirements and has these is preferred.

- Free or cheap
- E-mail capabilities
- Contact (people) capabilities
- Reasonable licence agreement (not unrealistically strict)
- Convenient to use (no frequent user frustration)
- Intuitive (not difficult to use, no obvious or significant design flaws)
- Responsive to open and use
- Native Windows UI (not using Java Swing, for example)
- No Windows 8-style UI
- Active development (not abandoned, discontinued or orphaned)
- Tasks can be split into subtasks
- Instant-messaging capabilities
- Single application (rather than multiple separate applications)

## Excluded Software

I have already tried or investigated the following applications and found them to be lacking in some of the above areas:

### [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) 17 + [Lightning](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning/) 1.9

- No support for multiple calendar accounts from the same provider
- No task synchronisation
- Development limited to bug-fixes and other minor maintenance work

### Mozilla Thunderbird 17 + Lightning 1.9 + [Provider for Google Calendar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/provider-for-google-calendar/) 0.18

- Calendar synchronisation glitches
- Lost calendar appointments
- No task synchronisation

### Microsoft Outlook 2007 + [Google Calendar Sync](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?&answer=98565)

- Google Calendar Sync appears to be discontinued
- No support for multiple accounts (from memory)
- Google Calendar Sync is a separate program

### Microsoft Outlook 2007 + [Hotmail Connector](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/outlook/microsoft-office-outlook-hotmail-connector-overview-HA010222518.aspx)

- No task synchronisation support

### [Windows Live Mail](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-live/essentials-other-programs?T1=t2)

- No task support

### Windows 8 Calendar

- No task support
- Reminders only show once
- Reminders only show momentarily (user might not even be looking at the screen)
- Low-productivity Windows 8-style UI

### [eM Client 5](http://www.emclient.com/)

- Frequent crashes and errors
- Disappearing events and tasks (data loss)
- Data corruption
- Poor repeating tasks support (reminders not working, occurrences not being created, basically a hack)
- Unrealistic licence agreement

### [Kontact](http://userbase.kde.org/Kontact)

- Unstable (*experimental* status according to [this wiki page](https://wiki.kolab.org/Client_windows_kontact))

### [Chandler](http://chandlerproject.org/)

- No active development
- Unreliable reminders
- Poor performance
- Poor UI

### [Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/)

- Unstable (*experimental* status according to [the download page](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/download.shtml))

### [Zimbra Desktop](http://www.zimbra.com/products/desktop.html)

- No repeating tasks
- Non-native UI
- Slow UI

### [VueMinder](http://www.vueminder.com/)

- Extremely poor UI performance
- UI contrast issues

### [Pimero](http://www.pimero.com/en/)

- Requires the use of a server to synchronise with online services.
- Appears to be intended for businesses and workgroups.

Comment: Why was this closed, specifically? Is it considered *asking for a shopping or product recommendation*?

Comment: For anyone who's interested, I ended up settling with [Outlook.com](http://www.outlook.com) and Windows Live Mail. Windows Live Mail doesn't provide task support, but I personally felt that it was the best compromise for me. As an added bonus, Outlook.com supports ActiveSync, so I can sync the contacts, mail, tasks and calendars with my phone. Using the new Microsoft Outlook 2013 with Outlook.com should work fine for all of the requirements, but I felt that it was very expensive.

Comment: Just an update to the above comment: it looks like Windows 8 Mail is gradually making Windows Live Mail obsolete. It's usable at this stage, but still prerelease quality.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [EssentialPIM](http://www.essentialpim.com/pc-version/features). I've stumbled over this some time ago when looking for something else. I haven't tried it but it seems to live up to your requirements. It's up to you to decide if USD 40 is too expensive.

Comment: Thanks; it does appear to meet all of the requirements. I intend to use the trial version for a while to see how reliable it is and determine if it has any flaws that could get in my way.

Comment: I've found the following flaws with it already.
-Can't control which calendars are subscribed to (within a single online service account).
-Doesn't display all contacts' details from online service.
-No "Agenda" view.
-Doesn't seem to subscribe to 'push' IMAP functionality.
-Unintelligent mail account set-up wizard.

Of course, I'll still consider it. Hopefully there's something better out there.

Answer (score -1):

The Absolute BEST of all time was Ecco PRO. No sync though. I want a PIM that can sync with Google tasks....I am using GTO in a SG2. I need something better than the standard Google Windows front....

Comment: Have you run across a PIM that has synchronization support or meets some of the other needs identified in the question?

Comment: @chuff, keep in mind that as a new user, Gino isn't allowed to post comments, so this is one of the only ways to contribute to the site. The answer doesn't address the criteria, but I see this as a symptom of a design flaw in the StackExchange network.

Comment: Good point, @Sam. As a fairly new user to the site myself, I appreciate helpful suggestions.

Comment: Gino, what are "GTO" and "SG2"? Also, you can mark this question as a "Favourite" to keep track of its answers.